# Is it a bad practice to use array as a sort of dictionary key?

Tags: python, dictionary

In python arrays cannot initially be used as a dictionary key, however I would convert the array into a string separated with commas which can now be used as a dictionary key. I used this technique in leetcode problems such as 3sum and 4sum which gets accepted using this technique:

1. sort array
2. convert array to string
3. store in dictionary
4. check for duplicates in O(1) time

This is my entire solution for 3sum using this technique:

```
class Solution(object):
def threeSum(self, nums):
    finreturn = []
    dict = {}
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if nums[i] in dict:
            dict[nums[i]]=dict[nums[i]]+1
        else:
            dict[nums[i]]=1
    comparedict = {}
    for key1 in dict:
        for key2 in dict:
            if -(key1+key2) in dict:
                dict[key1]=dict[key1]-1
                dict[key2]=dict[key2]-1
                dict[-(key1+key2)]=dict[-(key1+key2)]-1
                tempdict = [key1,key2,-(key1+key2)]
                tempdict.sort()
                compare = str(tempdict[0])+','+str(tempdict[1])+','+str(tempdict[2])
                if dict[key1]>=0 and dict[key2]>=0 and dict[-(key1+key2)]>=0 and compare not in comparedict: #comparing in O(1) time here 
                    finreturn.append(tempdict)
                    #using this technique here
                    comparedict[str(tempdict[0])+','+str(tempdict[1])+','+str(tempdict[2])]=1
                dict[key1]=dict[key1]+1
                dict[key2]=dict[key2]+1
                dict[-(key1+key2)]=dict[-(key1+key2)]+1
    return finreturn
```

Comment: You can join strings like this: `','.join(['cat', 'sat', 'mat'])` to yield `'cat,sat,mat'`.

Comment: A _tuple_, unlike a list, is an appropriate key.

Answer (score 0):

General design principle would be that the key of a dictionary should be an immutable data structure. This way, once an entry in dictionary is made, it can be predictably retrieved via the same key.

A string is immutable, so it is good choice for a key.